# How do I AddRef() an nsCOMPtr for use as an out param?

Tags: firefox-addon, smart-pointers, xpcom, reference-counting, geckosdk

I have a member for my class:

```
class MyNativeXPCOMObject ... {
    ...
private:
    nsCOMPtr<nsISomeInterface> someInterface_;
    ...
};
```

I have methods that do this:

```
NS_IMETHODIMP MyNativeXPCOMObject::GetSomeObject(nsISomeInterface** aSomeInterface) {
    NS_IF_ADDREF(someInterface_);
    *aSomeInterface = someInterface_;
    return NS_OK;
}
```

But Gecko 9 enforces that you're not allowed to call `AddRef()` or `Release()` on `nsCOMPtr<>`s.  So now I'm doing this:

```
NS_IMETHODIMP MyNativeXPCOMObject::GetSomeObject(nsISomeInterface** aSomeInterface) {
    NS_IF_ADDREF(someInterface_.get());  // <--- Added .get()!
    *aSomeInterface = someInterface_;
    return NS_OK;
}
```

But directly accessing the raw pointer makes me feel dirty.  What is the proper way to `AddRef()` for out params in getters?

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsCOMPtr/Reference_Manual#Writing_Getters) was not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply change the instruction order:

```
*aSomeInterface = someInterface_;
NS_IF_ADDREF(*aSomeInterface);
```

`*aSomeInterface` is a raw pointer so you can use `NS_IF_ADDREF` on it. That's how most Gecko code seems to do it.

Comment: Sigh.  Yes, that would be the obvious thing to do.  :)